# Powershell SmtpClient error

Tags: powershell

Fairly new to powershell, grabbed a script and modified it a bit for my situation. Not sure why SmtpClient isn't working. As far as I can tell, I followed how to use the command properly.

```
param ([switch]$configure)

$Date = Get-Date

$Server = gc env:computername

$EmailFrom = "email@email.com"

$EmailTo = "email2@email.com"

$Subject = "Hardware Alert from $Server $Date"

$SMTPServer = "smtp.office365.com"

$SMTPPort = '587'

$SMTPUser = 'email@email.com'

$SMTPPassword = 'hunter2'


else{SmtpClient.Send($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)}
```

Comment: The body is just from here  http://lemonfilling.com/Tech/omalert.html, was flagged as spam

Comment: What do you mean by saying isn't working? Do you get any error message? Why not use PowerShell built in cmdlet Send-MailMessage?

Comment: I phrased that oddly. I get "the server response was 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM"

Comment: Why not just use [send-mailmessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-5.1) command?

Answer (score 0):

Password had to be refreshed. Despite not saying so, you need to change the password once every three months for this method to work with office, apparently.